# Create a map out of vector of tags and a form

Tags: clojure, zipmap

I want to write a generalized version out of this code

```
(fn[item] 
 {:tag1 ($x:text "./tag1" item) 
  :tag2 ($x:text "./tag2" item)})
```

I was thinking of using zipmap, because I'd use a vector of tags, like this

```
[:tag1 :tag2],
```

but don't know how to make a generalized version of form

```
($x:text "./tag1" item)
```

for any given item from the vector.

Any ideas?

Comment: where are `$x:tag1` and `$x:tag2` defined, and what do they do? Also, you have one too many `{` in your example - or perhaps one too few `}`

Comment: this would be part of the function which would have as input parameters a vector that would consist out of tags, [:tag1 :tag2], and yes I have one { to many...

Comment: do you intend for `$x:tag1` to be the name of a function, or is it `$x` with `:tag1` as its first arg, and the space is missing?

Comment: no, excuse me, my bad, just saw that $x :is with :text, not :tag, I copied the wrong code

Comment: it is a clj-xpath function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible with `zipmap`, by using the same collection twice:

```
(fn [item]
  (let [tags [:tag1 :tag2]]
    (zipmap tags
            (map (fn [tag]
                   ($x:text (str "./" (name tag)) item))
                 tags))))
```

but I think it is actually clearer using `into`:

```
(fn [item]
  (into {}
        (map (fn [tag]
               [tag ($x:text (str "./" (name tag)) item)])
             [:tag1 :tag2])))
```